# File uploading, transfer and storage

Tags: php, mysql, email, file-io

I'm creating a simple mail system in PHP. And I'm stuck in this situation. I want to add a feature where my system can also do a file uploading and transferring. But I don't know how to add the file into mysql database. Any tips would be appreciated

compose.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="" id="someForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<legend>Compose Mail</legend>

<!-- Text input-->


<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="sendto">Send To: </label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="sendto" name="sendto" placeholder="Send To" class="input-xlarge cmps" type="text">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Text input-->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="title">Title: </label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title/Subject" class="input-xlarge cmps" type="text">
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Textarea -->
<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="body">Message: </label>
  <div class="controls">                     
    <textarea id="body" name="body" class="cmps"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="control-group">
  <label class="control-label" for="file">File: </label>
  <div class="controls">
    <input id="file" name="file" type="file">
  </div>
</div>

<button type="submit" id="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="askForSubmit()">Send!</button>
<button type="submit" id="button" class="btn-danger btn" onclick="askForSave()">Save to drafts</button>

</fieldset>
</form>

<script>
form=document.getElementById("someForm");
function askForSave() {
        form.action="http://rsantiago.mbchosting.ph/email/save.php";
        form.submit();
}
function askForSubmit() {
        form.action="http://rsantiago.mbchosting.ph/email/send.php";
        form.submit();
}


</script>
```

the upload_file.php

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 30000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 30000) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

I just wanna know how to store the file into the database so when the user sends it to another user, it can be downloaded

Comment: Too many questions like these on SO and to be found on Google. What have you searched, how much time was invested and what have you tried?

Comment: dont add the file to the db, store it in a folder, store its location\name in the db

Comment: ...and if you absolutely want/need to store the actual file in DB, Google "blob".

Comment: You don't want to save the file contents in the database right? You want to save the filename. `$_FILES['file']['name']` contains the filename.

Comment: Thanks!! Will research about BLOB right away :)

Comment: You're welcome, however it's not recommended. Your DB will increase in size dramatically. It's a lot easier to Query also and using the file's location using `<img src="codes"...` "after the fact" ;-)

Comment: People **REALLY** need to stop using the W3fools upload handling code. it is such a pile of crap and so utterly full of vulnerabilities.